# COMODO HIPS firewall spamming me

Tags: malware, anti-virus

I recently setup my windows system with a Comodo Firewall. The only issue is, whenever I install/run a program that needs to either connect to a specific port or modify a reg key, Comodo goes nuts and requests my authentication for EVERY single behavior within its boot process.

So for example, if I run the program 'legitcheck.hta' for the first time. It will send me at LEAST 20 requests to allow its various connections and/or privileged modifications.

A lot of the time, I just want to be able to click `'Allow all modifications by program x'`

Could anyone help me out? I'm super impressed with a lot of the options Comodo provides, but this one is a game breaker.

The worst thing is it makes a sound every time it asks me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://help.comodo.com/topic-72-1-284-2969-.html

**- How to make execeptions for programs -**

Click on 'Define a New Trusted Application' link in Firewall Tasks . A dialog box appears prompting you to select the application you want to trust. Click the 'Select' button. You now have 3 methods available to choose the application that you want to          trust - 'File Groups'; 'Running Processes' and 'Browse...'.
File Groups - Choosing this option allows you to choose your application from a category of pre-set files or folders. For example, selecting 'Executables' would enable you to create an allow rule for any file that attempts to connect to the Internet with the extensions .exe .dll .sys .ocx .bat .pif .scr .cpl . Other such categories available include 'Windows System Applications' , 'Windows Updater Applications' , 'Start Up Folders' and so on - each of which provide a fast and convenient way to batch select important files and folders. 
Running Processes - as the name suggests, this option allows you to choose the target application from a list of processes that are currently running on your PC.
Browse... - this option is the easiest for most users and simply allows you to browse to the location of the application which you want to trust.
When you have chosen the application using one of the methods above, the application name appears along with its location:
Click 'Apply' to confirm your choice.